# Proof of Expected Value for Independent random variables with two possibilities

Tags: probability, expectation

Let ${B_i}$ ($i=$natural number) be a random variable which takes $1$ with probability $p$ and takes $-1$ with probability $1-p$ where $0<p<1$. Assume that ${B_i}$ and ${B_j}$ are independent if $i \neq j$. Let  ${S_N}=\sum_{i=1}^{N} {B_i}$ ($N=$Natural Number) and $E[.]$ denote expectation.

Show that 
$E\left[{B_i}^m{B_j}^n\right]=E\left[{B_i}^m\right]E\left[{B_j}^n\right]$ for any natural numbers $m$ and $n$ if $i\neq j$.

I am really new to this subject, so I hope someone experienced can help show me how I should prove this.

Comment: Being new to the subject $\implies$ Nothing to say about the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$. This result does not depend on the type of random variables.

This is because $$E(XY)=\sum_{x,y}xyP(X=x,Y=y)=\sum_{x,y}xyP(X=x)P(Y=y)\\=\Big(\sum_xxP(X=x)\Big)\Big(\sum_yyP(Y=y)\Big),$$
which uses independence to go between the second and third expressions.

For sums, much more is true: $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$ even if the variables are not independent.

The $n$ and $m$ in your question are a distraction. $X_i=\pm1$ so if $m$ is odd then $X_i^m\equiv X_i$, and if $m$ is even then $X^m\equiv E(X^m)=1$.

Comment: $(-1)^{m}=+1$ not $-1$ for even integer $m$

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is easy to understand :)

Answer (score -1):

In probability theory, two random variables are said to independent when joint distribution$ F_{A,B}(a, b) = F_A(a)F_B(b)$. When densities exist then $f_{A,B}(a, b) = f_A(a)f_B(b)$

In your case $E[B^m_i, B^n_j] = \sum_{b_i,b_j \in \{\pm1\}^2} b^m_ib^n_j f_{B_i, B_j}(b_i,b_j) = \sum_{b_i, b_j \in \{\pm1\}^2} b^m_ib^n_j f_{B_i}(b_i)f_{B_j}(b_j)$

$=\sum_{b_i \in\{\pm1\}} b^m_i f_{B_i}(b_i)\sum_{b_j \in \{\pm1\}}b^n_j f_{B_j}(b_j) = E(B^m_i)E(B^n_j)$

Comment: One cannot recommend notations such as $F(A, B)$, $F(A)$, $F(B)$, $f(A, B)$, $f(A)$, $f(B)$, or $E(U,V)$, all in your post. Additionally, I wonder what an *existing and infinite density* could refer to.

Comment: @Did  I will keep this in mind thanks, not to use too many terms. What would have been better way to answer this. Thanks

Comment: The number of terms is irrelevant, but to use canonical notations is relevant, for example the CDF and PDF of some random variable $X$ are quasi universally denoted $F_X$ and $f_X$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering!