# Interchanging Sum and Expected Value Operators

Tags: summation, operator-theory, expected-value

The manipulability of expected value operators and sum operators is something that often confuses me. So, two questions: (1) Can they also be interchanged like so

$\text{E}\bigg(\sum\limits_{t=1}^{T}(a_tu_t)\bigg)=\sum\limits_{t=1}^{T}\text{E}\bigg(a_tu_t\bigg)=\sum\limits_{t=1}^{T}\text{E}(a_t)\text{E}(u_t)=\text{E}\bigg(\sum\limits_{t=1}^{T}(a_t)\sum\limits_{t=1}^{T}(u_t)\bigg)$

And (2) are there any general rules worth mentioning which may make it easier to deal with these things in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interchanging of the expected value operators and the sum operators is valid because of linearity of expectation. The splitting from $\mathbb{E}(a_tu_t)$ to $\mathbb{E}(a_t)\mathbb{E}(u_t)$ is only true when $a_t$ and $u_t$ are independent (for all $t$).

The last "equality" that you state is in general never true. Unless we happened to have independence and $u_ra_t=0$ when $r\neq t$. This could also possibly be true in some other forced cases, but it would not be something you can rely on in most cases.

Comment: Are you able to explain why it is that splitting $E(a_tu_t)$ into $E(a_t)E(u_t)$ is only true when $a_t$ and $u_t$ and independent? This isn't obvious to me...

Comment: @RyanWalter It's a property of the expected value operator, it is proven in here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287504/proof-of-expected-value-for-independent-random-variables-with-two-possibilities/2287516#:~:text=If%20two%20random%20variables%20X,the%20type%20of%20random%20variables.

Comment: Because the definition of covariance is $\mathsf{Cov}(a_t,u_t)=\mathsf E(a_tu_t)-\mathsf E(a_t)~\mathsf E(u_t)$.  So for you require the random variables to be at least *uncorrelated* for the expectation of the product to equal the product of their expectations.